# How to change browser in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was just scratching my head while finding a way to switch the browser as we do in Visual Studio but I think there is no straight forward way to do this in VS Code. could somebody tell me the way I can change the browser in VS Code to view output in different browsers?

Comment: have you tried in seetimgs?

Comment: what is seetimgs? I'm new to VS Code, I don't know what is that @federicoscamuzzi

Comment: Which plugin are you using to open page in browser?

Comment: This has no connection to angularjs!

Comment: you can customize your settings ... go to file menu --> preferences --> settings

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, just change your default browser to Chrome. Then restart VS Code and run your app - it should now open in Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

In Extentions, select Spring Boot Dashboard, after click Manage and select extension settings, after select external on propertie Spring>dashboard:Open with